# Burn MaixPy on Sipeed M1W

Tags: cmake, micropython

I am using Sipeed M1W and its LCD display white screen after I burned the [demo](https://github.com/kendryte/kendryte-standalone-demo/tree/master/hello_world).
Then I built and compiled MaixPy and burned micropython.bin to the board but it's still white and display following message on the terminal.

```
Official Site:http://www.sipeed.com/
Wiki:http://maixpy.sipeed.com/
[MAIXPY]Pll0:freq:320666666
[MAIXPY]Pll1:freq:159714285
[MAIXPY]Flash:0xc8:0x17
[MAIXPY]:Spiffs Mount successful 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "boot.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "init.py", line 4, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 5] EIO

MicroPython d58620d on 2018-12-11; Sipeed_M1 with kendryte-k210
Type "help()" for more information.
>>>
```

According to the document it seems something go wrong in camera, but I don't know how to fix it or where I can find .bin to burn to the board make it works.

Answer (score 0):

I got some help in the telegram group for this.

"You can delete code "import app" in boot.py, then compile and burn it agian"

but what worked for me finally was doing the extra step...

```
make pack_kfpkg
```

The kfpkg file will be in: C:\abc\MaixPy\ports\k210-standalone and you should flash that.

I put a MicroPython on the M1W board install guide on my blog here: https://robotzero.one/sipeed-maix-micropython/